# jquery ajax to insert and load data from database

Tags: jquery, ajax

Not able to insert and load data using this code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});




$(function() {

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var test = $("#txtarea").val();
        var dataString = 'question=' + test;
        if (test == '') {
            alert("<h3>Please Enter Some Text</h3>");
        } else {
            $("#loading").show();
            $("#loading").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="loading">Loading Comment...</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'q&a.php',
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                error: function() {
                    $('#loading').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
                },
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#cm").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('txtarea').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('txtarea').focus();
                    $("#load").hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: kindly more details to the question

Comment: trying to insert data and fetch data using this jquery ajax code but not working.

Comment: i am trying to do the same as the stackoverflow 'add comment' section works

Comment: Don't call `.show()` before calling `.fadeIn` -- there's nothing to fade if the DIV is already visible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL-encode the data value, in case it contains special characters. The easiest way to do that is to use an object instead of a string; jQuery will encode it automatically.

```
var datastring = { question: test };
```

BTW, it's generally not necessary to use `cache: false` with `type: "POST"`. Browsers should not cache `POST` responses, only `GET` responses.

Also, in your `success` function you're hiding the wrong ID. It should be `$("#loading").hide()`.